# How can I plot an arbitrary color function on the plane?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In python, suppose I want to write a python function taking a point (x, y) and returning a color. What's the simplest way to plot that function over a rectangle? I have numpy and matplotlib already, but I'm willing to install any other free libraries. From experience, matplotlib seems to make it a bit of a pain, I don't want to have to do anything more complicated than:

```
from library import plot

def f(x, y):
    # etc

plot(f, xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would be an example where a color function `f` maps coordinates `x` and `y` to an RGB array. Given some input coordinates on a grid, you can evaluate `f` and show it as image.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# color function, from input (x,y) in the range between 0 and 1
# return an RGB tuple
f = lambda x,y: np.stack((x,np.zeros_like(x),y), axis=2)

# input grid of values between 0 and 1
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1,51),np.linspace(0,1,51))
# plot function:
plt.imshow(f(X,Y))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: But then f isn't a function taking numbers x and y, right? I have to make sure to program f so that it's compatible with numpy arrays, instead of being able to focus purely on the logic of what color a given pixel should be.

Comment: f takes two numpy arrays `x` and `y` as input. What exactly is your requirement concerning `x` and `y`?

Comment: That they both be python floats.

Comment: If the function takes arbitrary floats what should the output image be like? Single dots?

Comment: The output should be like the image you posted.

Comment: But in order to get that image you anyways need a grid, so you may directly supply this grid to the function.